# Can you apply CSS to only a segment of an innerText without using Javascript's .surroundContent()?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I am wondering if there is a way to assign CSS to a particular segment of an HTMLelement.innerText without surrounding the segment with its own HTML element such as "span". For instance, applying a background-color to just the "DEF" of the innerText below. Most solution I came across used slice(), replace() or surroundContent(), but I am specifically looking for a solution without amending the innerText or innerHTML. I am not knowledgeable on CSS selectors, but this doesn't seem to be an option here either.

```html
<div id="test">ABCDEFGHI</div>
```

Comment: I do not know of any solution that does not involve splitting the content in some way and adding more tags. The only thing I can think of is [`first-letter`](https://caniuse.com/css-first-letter), but unfortunatelly there is no [`nth-letter`](https://www.bram.us/2012/04/13/css-nth-letter/)

Comment: HTML tags are meant to add formatting to otherwise plain text. It doesn't really make sense to want to format text without using HTML tags to be honest... I recommend just using a `<span>`...

Comment: Thank you both. @Kokodoko I agree with your points, the thought crossed my mind because DOM manipulation was conditionally protected (and mutation reverted) on certain sites for the chrome extension I was playing around with and I figured if an answer to this existed, I'd give that a try. But if there was an answer, that would probably just be a part of the condition and throw the same error.